# How to correct this if statement with OR and AND in PHP?

Tags: php

I am trying to code this logic but I am having difficulties because

> If a or b exists and in the same time if c is more than 2010 AND d
>   more than 15.500 echo something.

```
<?php if ((($row['a'] >1) || ($row['b'] >1)) && (($row['c'] >=2010) && ($row['d'] >=15.500)))  { ?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "if a or b exists"? You're stating if the `a` or `b` fields are 2 or above there.

Comment: what is `$row`? whats wrong with this? seems ok.(if `$row['a']` is treated as `a`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `$row['a'] > 1` is how you check whether `a` exists, your only problem is that you should be using `>` rather than `>=`, like so:

```
if ((($row['a'] > 1) || ($row['b'] > 1)) && (($row['c'] > 2010) && ($row['d'] > 15.5)))
```

Expanded:

```
if (
    (
        ($row['a'] > 1) || ($row['b'] > 1) // a or b exist
    )
    && // and
    (
        ($row['c'] > 2010) && ($row['d'] > 15.5) // c more than 2010 and d more than 15.5
    )
)
```

Comment: well the `>=` doesn't seem to make a change

Comment: @Xalloumokkelos What is your test input? What's the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

With exists, maybe, you mean `isset` function?

```
if ( 
  (isset($row['a']) || isset($row['b'])) && 
  ($row['c'] > 2010 && $row['d'] > 15500) ) {
    echo 'something';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I've been able to work out what you were doing, I've come up with:

```
if (($row['a'] > 1) || ($row['b'] >1)) && (($row['c'] >= 2010) && ($row['d'] >= 15.500)) { echo "Something"; }
```

It is one if statement is it not, therefore there should only be one set of parenthesis.

Edit: This is assuming that $row['a'] > 1 is your method of checking.

Comment: Error on my part. Should now do as asker requested.

Comment: It still doesn't work. The "extra" parentheses are required, otherwise the evaluation short-circuits and results in `true` if `$row['a'] > 1`. See [this](http://ideone.com/AU9rDY) demonstration of what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

```
if 
   (
      (
        ($row['a'] > 1) || ($row['b'] > 1) // if a or b exists
      ) 

      && // at the same time

      (
        ($row['c'] > 2010) // c is more than 2010

        && // and

        ($row['d'] > 15.500) // d is more than 15.500
      )
   ) 
   {
      echo 'something.';
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Might as well add my version!

```
if ( (array_key_exists('a', $row) || array_key_exists('b', $row)) && ($row['c'] >=2010 && $row['d'] >=15.500) ) echo 'hello';
```

OP did specifically ask if a or b exists